# Is there a solution to set Margin of Frame with Datatrigger?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, datatemplate, datatrigger

I try to set the Margin of my frame with Binding. If the bindable value is true, the margin must be settled to "10,0" otherwise it must be settled to "10".

From my point of view, DataTrigger is the best way to achieve this. I made a DataTrigger to set some properties of my frame, like CornerRadius and Margin.

With that, the cornerRadius is setted as I want but not the Margin. So Bindable property is found.

I tried to set Margin directly in the Frame tag and it's work, but it not depend of Bindable property.

There is someone have a solution ?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="tache-template">
                <ViewCell>
                    <!--#region stl tâche-->
                    <StackLayout 
                        Orientation="Vertical" 
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="Fill"
                        Margin="0"
                        Padding="0"
                        Spacing="0">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Frame CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="False" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="0" Margin="10">
                                <Frame.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame" Binding="{Binding IsAssociated}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0"/>
                                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Frame.Triggers>
                                <StackLayout 
                                x:Name="tacheLandscape"
                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LightGrayCorim}"
                                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                Spacing="2">
                                    <controls:CustomTappedStackLayout 
                                    x:Name="imageTask"
                                    Orientation="Vertical"
                                    VerticalOptions="Fill"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                    Padding="5"
                                    Spacing="0"
                                    Margin="0" 
                                    BackgroundColor="White" 
                                    TappedBackgroundColor="#cbe6f1"
                                    MinimumWidthRequest="50" 
                                    WidthRequest="50"
                                    effects:LongPressedEffect.Command="{Binding BindingContext.OnSelectionModeCommand, Source={x:Reference page}}" 
                                    effects:LongPressedEffect.CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                                        <StackLayout.Effects>
                                            <effects:LongPressedEffect/>
                                        </StackLayout.Effects>
                                        <StackLayout 
                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                            <Image 
                                            IsVisible="{Binding BindingContext.SelectionTacheMode, Source={x:Reference page}, Converter={StaticResource NegateBooleanConverter}}"
                                            WidthRequest="30"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            Source="TacheBleu.png">
                                            </Image>
                                            <CheckBox
                                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                            IsEnabled="{Binding Model.ReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource NegateBooleanConverter}}"
                                            ClassId="{Binding Model.Tache.Id}"
                                            Color="{StaticResource BlueCorim}"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            IsVisible="{Binding BindingContext.SelectionTacheMode, Source={x:Reference page}}">
                                                <CheckBox.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger TargetType="CheckBox" Binding="{Binding Model.ReadOnly}" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Color" Value="Gray"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.6"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </CheckBox.Triggers>
                                            </CheckBox>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </controls:CustomTappedStackLayout>
                                    <controls:CustomTappedStackLayout
                                    BackgroundColor="White"
                                    TappedBackgroundColor="#cbe6f1"
                                    Orientation="Vertical"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    Padding="10"
                                    ClassId="{Binding Model.Tache.Id,StringFormat='tache_{0}'}">
                                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="onOpenItem"/>
                                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <StackLayout.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding LandscapeMode}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </StackLayout.Triggers>

                                        <StackLayout
                                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                            <StackLayout
                                            Orientation="Vertical"
                                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                <StackLayout
                                                Spacing="5"
                                                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                    <Grid ColumnSpacing="5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                        <Label 
                                                        Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                                                        Text="{trad:Translate tache,Converter={StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}"
                                                        TextColor="LightGray"
                                                        FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFont}"/>
                                                        <Label
                                                        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                                                        Text="{Binding Model.Tache.Libelle, Converter={StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}"
                                                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                                        MaxLines="2"
                                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                        VerticalOptions="Fill"
                                                        FontFamily="{StaticResource SemiBoldFont}"
                                                        FontSize="{x:StaticResource MediumTextSize}"
                                                        TextColor="Black"/>
                                                    </Grid>

                                                </StackLayout>

                                                <!--#region type de la tâche-->
                                                <Grid ColumnSpacing="5"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                    <Label
                                                    Text="{trad:Translate type, Converter={StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}"
                                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                    TextColor="LightGray"
                                                    FontFamily="{StaticResource SemiBoldFont}"
                                                    FontSize="{x:StaticResource MediumTextSize}"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                                    <Label
                                                    Text="{trad:Translate aucun_type,Converter={StaticResource UpperFirstCharConverter}}"
                                                    TextColor="LightGray"
                                                    FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFontItalic}"
                                                    FontSize="{StaticResource DefaultTextSize}"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                    VerticalOptions="Fill"
                                                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                                        <Label.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Model.Tache.TypeTache.Libelle,Converter={StaticResource StringEmptyBooleanConverter}}" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Model.Tache.TypeTache.Libelle}"/>
                                                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource RegularFont}"/>
                                                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Label.Triggers>
                                                    </Label>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <!--#endregion type de la tâche-->
                                                <!--#region note de la tâche-->
                                                <Grid ColumnSpacing="5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <Label
                                                    Text="{trad:Translate note, Converter={StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}"
                                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                    FontFamily="{StaticResource SemiBoldFont}"
                                                    FontSize="{x:StaticResource MediumTextSize}"
                                                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                    TextColor="LightGray"
                                                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                                    <Label 
                                                    Text="{trad:Translate aucune_note,Converter={StaticResource UpperFirstCharConverter}}"
                                                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                                    MaxLines="2"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                    TextColor="LightGray"
                                                    FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFontItalic}"
                                                    FontSize="{StaticResource DefaultTextSize}"
                                                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                                        <Label.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Model.Tache.Note, Converter={StaticResource StringEmptyBooleanConverter}}" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Model.Tache.Note}"/>
                                                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource DefaultTextSize}"/>
                                                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource RegularFont}"/>
                                                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Label.Triggers>
                                                    </Label>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <!--#endregion note de la tâche-->
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <Button 
                                        Clicked="OnShowTaskPicker" 
                                        IsEnabled="{Binding Model.ReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource NegateBooleanConverter}}"
                                        Text="{Binding StatutTache.Title}"
                                        BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColorTache}"
                                        TextColor="{Binding ForegroundColorTache}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        CornerRadius="10"
                                        HeightRequest="50">
                                            <Button.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding Model.ReadOnly}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.6"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Button.Triggers>
                                        </Button>
                                        <BoxView HeightRequest="2" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LightGrayCorim}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding IsAssociated}"/>
                                    </controls:CustomTappedStackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a demo and it works fine on my side .

> in xaml

I added two `Frames` and a `Button` . When you click the button ,the value of **IsAssociated** will been changed .

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
  <Frame CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="Blue" HasShadow="False" HeightRequest="200" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="0" Margin="10">
     <Frame.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame" Binding="{Binding IsAssociated}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
        </DataTrigger>
     </Frame.Triggers>
  </Frame>

  <Frame CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="Red" HasShadow="False" HeightRequest="200" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="0" Margin="10">
     <Frame.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame" Binding="{Binding IsAssociated}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
       </DataTrigger>
     </Frame.Triggers>
  </Frame>

  <Button Text="Click Me" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>

</StackLayout>
```

> in code behind

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    bool isAssociated;
    public bool IsAssociated
    {
        get { return isAssociated; }

        set
        {
            isAssociated = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();               
        }
    }
  
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this;

        IsAssociated = false;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsAssociated = !IsAssociated;
    }
}
```

I did it in code behind just for test . You can implement it in your viewmodel.

## Update

If you set the `ViewCell` as a **Frame** directly,it will maybe cause some issue. because it will not fit the size of its child elements .

Improve the layout of your `Datatemplate`

```
<DataTemplate>
  <ViewCell>
    <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

       <Frame Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="200" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="False" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="0" Margin="10">
         <Frame.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame" Binding="{Binding IsAssociated}" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0"/>
           <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
          </DataTrigger>
        </Frame.Triggers>
      </Frame>
    </Grid>
  </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I dont unterstand why it's work for you and not me. I've realized that refresh page help sometimes to set margin... Do you think the problem is about Listview and Datatemplate? (the frame is inside a DataTemplate)

Comment: You can share a sample which contains your issue so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Thank you for reply, I tried with a Frame inside Grid inside StackLayout in my ViewCell and it still doesn't work.

I've edited my post with my datatemplate.

Comment: Just put the grid in  datatemplate . Refer my code .

Comment: Above code works fine on my side . So you can share a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: So. After tried many solutions (Grid inside ViewCell, change padding instead Margin, set a Bindable Margin), none of them has worked. So I found an ugly solution. I've created one template more with the good margin, and in my templateSelector I choose the right template in function of value of IsAssociated.

I know it's a dirty solution, thank you for your help!